# How to use BottomNavigationView to switch between two app screens

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

The problem is:
I've created an app with one screen that holds ViewPager (holds cards) and BottomNavigationView. But now i need to add functionality to switch to "about" screen.

Question:
How to switch to "about" layout and back the best way? "about" is just simple layout with few textViews (no data transfer between screens needed)

I've tried to rewrite my classes and create the top-hierarchy Main class that will hold another ViewPager that will hold Fragments (Viewpager with cards AND "about" layout ) and switch between them, but at the moment it didn't really worked, maybe there is an easier way to show "about" on the top of the "home", and then back?

[image: app look]

My NavigationItemSelectedListener is in MainActivity:

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    // change screen
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_about:
                    // change screen
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // other code here ...

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        // other code here ...

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one of the possible ways to do it:

in main_layout I've created constraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/aboutLayer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" <--- BACKGROUND NOT TRANSPARENT
    android:visibility="invisible" <--- INVISIBLE
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in listener just change visibility of the layer

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                // hide about
                aboutInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_about:
                // show about
                aboutInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ViewPager` use `FrameLayout`. Then create two fragments. One fragment with the `ViewPager` and the other fragment for the About view. On `BottomNavigationView` click just replace the suitable fragment.

Hope it helps. :)